# PNG imports wrong in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, png

I try to add a PNG file as image asset in Android Studio. The PNG file has a transparent background, but also a white area inside it which completely disapears as shown in the image below. The image to the left is what the PNG looks like and the images to the right is how they look in Android Studio. Why is that?

[image: Image in A-Studio]

The original image file:
[image: original image]

Comment: Does the image appear correctly in your application? If not, post the original PNG so we have something other than a screen shot to look at.

Comment: No, the png file does not look correct in the app either. Here is a link to the file https://ibb.co/ikMCFf

Comment: Checking with `pngcheck`, the image itself seems undamaged and perfectly normal. This suggests a bug in Android Studio itself (so I suggest using "*imports* wrong" in your title).